# How to print an element from one list if it exists in another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, arraylist, nested-loops

```
list1 = ['moonlight black','mint cream','electric black','deep blue',
         'black','blue','flowing silver','crystal blue','ink black']
list2 = ["blue","black"]
          
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j in i:
            print(j)
        else:
            print("not found")
```

Output:  (I don't want this)

```
not found
black
not found
not found
not found
black
blue
not found
not found
black
blue
not found
not found
not found
blue
not found
not found
black
```

I want to print the `'blue'` or `'black'` if it exists in (or substring of) item in `list_1`, and print `not found` if neither `'blue'`  or `'black'` exists in the string value of `list_1`. But my code is not working. I want my output look like this:

```
black
not found
black
blue
black
blue
not found
blue
black
```

Answer (score 1):

as we have strigs here it has sence to use regex, like this:

```
from re import search

for i in list1:
    print(m[0] if (m:=search('|'.join(list2),i)) else 'not found')

>>>
'''
black
not found
black
blue
black
blue
not found
blue
black
```

Comment: I think it would be better to not build the search pattern for every item from `list1` again: once, compiled, before the loop instead?

Comment: @Timus, yeah, you're right

Answer (score 0):

update your code:

```
list1 = ['moonlight black','mint cream','electric black','deep blue',
         'black','blue','flowing silver','crystal blue','ink black']
list2 = ["blue","black"]
         
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j in i:
            print(j)
            break 
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use list comprehension

```
list1 = ['moonlight black','mint cream','electric black','deep blue','black','blue','flowing silver','crystal blue','ink black']
list2 = [print('black') if 'black' in color else print('blue') if 'blue' in color else print('not found') for color in list1]
```